# Vim leaving behind character after saving with :w not sure why

Tags: terminal

I'm running into a weird behaviour where I'm editing a file and saving it with the :w command.

The problem is it leaves behind the 'w' character after my line of edit. It doesn't do it all the time but its often enough to become a problem. The actual 'w' character isn't there because if I close and reopen the file, character disappear.

I'm not sure whats causing it.

eg.

```
    activate() {
        return this.productService
            .getAll()
            .then(products = this.products = products);**w**
    }

NOTE: the 'w' after the semi-colon.
```

**:verb au BufWrite** produced:

```
--- Auto Command ---
```

**:verb au BufWritePost** produced:

```
--- Auto-Commands ---
airline  BufWritePost
    */autoload/airline/themes/*.vim
              exec 'source '.split(globpath(&rtp, 'autoload/airline/themes/'.g:airline_theme.'.vim', 1), "\n")[0] | call airline#load_theme()
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/airline/plugin/airline.vim
CtrlPMRUF  BufWritePost
    *         cal s:record(expand('<abuf>', 1))
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp/autoload/ctrlp/mrufiles.vim
gitgutter  BufWritePost
    *         if gettabvar(tabpagenr(), 'gitgutter_didtabenter') |   call settabvar(tabpagenr(), 'gitgutter_didtabenter', 0) | else |   call gitgutter#process_buffer(bufnr(''), 0) | endif
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/gitgutter/plugin/gitgutter.vim
syntastic  BufWritePost
    *         call s:BufWritePostHook()
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim
gzip  BufWritePost
    *.gz      call gzip#write("gzip")
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.712_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
    *.bz2     call gzip#write("bzip2")
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.712_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
    *.Z       call gzip#write("compress -f")
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.712_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
    *.lzma    call gzip#write("lzma -z")
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.712_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
    *.xz      call gzip#write("xz -z")
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.712_1/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
BufWritePost
    <buffer=1>
              call s:JSHint()
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/jshint/ftplugin/javascript/jshint.vim
airline_whitespace  BufWritePost
    *         unlet! b:airline_whitespace_check
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
TagbarAutoCmds  BufWritePost
    *         call s:AutoUpdate(fnamemodify(expand('<afile>'), ':p'), 1)
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/tagbar/autoload/tagbar.vim
BufWritePost
    <buffer=7>
              call s:JSHint()
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/jshint/ftplugin/javascript/jshint.vim
    <buffer=15>
              call s:JSHint()
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/jshint/ftplugin/javascript/jshint.vim
    <buffer=34>
              call s:JSHint()
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/jshint/ftplugin/javascript/jshint.vim
    <buffer=54>
              call s:JSHint()
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/jshint/ftplugin/javascript/jshint.vim
    <buffer=55>
              call s:JSHint()
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/jshint/ftplugin/javascript/jshint.vim
    <buffer=56>
              call s:JSHint()
```

Comment: Do you have any autocommands that execute when you save? You can check by running without plugins, or by looking at the output of `:verb au BufWrite` and `:verb au BufWritePost`. (The gzip entries are expected.)

Comment: @joeytwiddle Added both entry into my question, I'm not vary familiar with these or buffers.

Comment: Hmm JSHint rings a bell. I might have had the same trouble with it myself! You could disable it to check. Failing that, try disabling Syntastic. Or a workaround might be to add your own hook to refresh the screen: `:au BufWritePost * :redraw!`

Comment: @joeytwiddle I'll see how it goes, but sometimes when you type, you think you've made a mistake or had extra letters but in actual fact they are not really there. It's not specifically just the 'w' character sometimes I get x or other symbols etc Thanks anyways.

Comment: <Ctrl-L> is always there to set your mind at ease. :) It would be great to get it fixed in the general case. I still get it with other plugins sometimes.

Comment: This is a known issue and happens usually, when vim is busy leaving stray letters around (usually the ones you typed last) and can be cleared by `Ctrl-L`.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt oh its a known issue, is it new? I never really had this issue previously. I've been using vim for quiet a while now. This is probably the first time I see it.